# Webpack get filename of one chunk in different chunk as env variable

Tags: webpack

I have two entry points in my webpack configuration:

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path')


module.exports = () => ({
    entry: {
        init: path.resolve(__dirname, 'init.js'),
        bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle.js'),
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
})
```

init.js

```js
const bundleScriptElement = document.createElement('script')
bundleScriptElement.src = 'http://example.com/[GET_BUNDLE_FILENAME_WITH_HASH_HERE]'
document.head.append(bundleScriptElement)
```

bundle.js

```js
console.log('test')
```

As you can see I would like to access the bundle filename as an env variable in `index.js`. Is there any option to achieve that with a pure webpack?

I guess I will need to do some postprocessing and use find and replace (via `sed`) after files are generated. But it would be nice if there is an "easier" solution.

Note: I cannot use dynamic imports, which would make life easier, because of compatibility reasons.